# vim javascript configuration for indentation

Tags: javascript, vim, indentation

I can't find a way to name this problem, thus I can't google it myself :/

How do I tell vim to indent like this :

```
someObject
  .firstThing
  .stuff()
```

instead of

```
someObject
.firstThing
.stuff()
```

I'm currently using [pangloss vim-javascript](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript) plugin and I suspect there is some configuration to do, but I couldn't find it.

Thanks !

Comment: Temporary solution. Indent all lines starting with a .    :%s/(?=\S)\./\s./g